# How to open Show Hide colum dialog on Right Click jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

In jqGrid how can I open "Show/Hide column" dialog as a contextmenu? Currently I wrote little small piece of code which open "Show/Hide column" dialog but it also show the normal right click context menu. But I don't want the usual right click context menu.

Here is an existing code

```
@(Html.Grid("Basic")

      .SetCaption("Basic Grid")

      .AddColumn(new Column("Id")
                     .SetHidden(true))

      .AddColumn(new Column("Name"))
      .AddColumn(new Column("Age"))

      .SetRequestType(RequestType.Get)
      .SetForceFit(true)
      .SetShrinkToFit(true)
      .SetUrl("/Home/Data/")
      .SetAutoWidth(true)
      .SetRowNum(10)
      .SetRowList(new[] { 10, 15, 20 })
      .SetViewRecords(true)
      .SetPager("pager")
      .SetDataType(DataType.Json)
      .SetLoadOnce(true)
      .SetGridView(true)
      .SetSortOrder(SortOrder.Asc)
      .OnPaging("onPaging()")
      .SetToolbar(true)
      .SetToolbarPosition(ToolbarPosition.Top)
      .OnGridComplete("onComplete()")
      .OnRightClickRow("onRightClick()"))
```

Here is a function which fires when I press right click

```
<script>

    function onRightClick() {
       $('#Basic').setColumns();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you try: `$('#Basic').on('contextmenu',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});`  ???

Comment: Should be: `e.target` not `event.target`

Comment: yes, it works. But how can I achieve the required functionality. e.target return the col id.

Comment: e.target returns the element which fired the event, in most case the grid cell not column. So you are looking for getting the column ID or what?

Comment: I want to hide that targeted cell for all rows. Plus if someone click Show All Column all the hidden column should appear.

Comment: " want to hide that targeted cell for all rows." So you want to hide the column??? Your sentence doesn't make much sense as there is only one targetted cell, not one on each row

Comment: Yes, I want to hide the column for all rows. We can get the target cell id on right click, so I think there must be some way to hide the column for each row by taking an advantage of cell id ? What you think, is it possible?